# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Local Database in Server Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, server-explorer, seeding

I have created an Internet Site in MVC 4 & EF5. I have followed a tutorial that allows me to seed Users & Roles directly to the Database via migration.

I can log into the site using the seeded Usernames so I know for sure they have been created.

However, I am unable to access the Database in Server Explorer. When I update the database using the package Manager Console like this :-

```
update-database - Verbose
```

It creates the new users, if any and tells me that the target database is :-

> Target database is: 'aspnet-MvcSeed-20130104100623' (DataSource:
>   .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).

However, this doesnt appear in my solutions Explorer and I'm struggling to Add the connection too it?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve this myself.

The folder that these mdf files are created and hosted in is as follows :-

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

From the Server Explorer, you need to add a new Data Connection and change the Datasource to:-

> Microsoft SQL Server Database File

You then browse to the above directory and there you will find your database.mdf file.

In Visual Studio 2012, this is automatically generated in Server Explorer, but when using Visual Studio 2010 I have had to connect to the database file manually like above.

Hopefully this will help out others in the future.